# Unable to create thumb, image is black

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

Am uploading Multiple image from single input and create thumb form all uploaded image on fly But **when i run code i get only black image but orginal image is same as uploaded**

```
    <?php

$newname = md5(rand() * time());
$file1 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][0] : null;
$file2 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][1]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][1] : null;
$file3 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][2]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][2] : null;
$file4 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][3]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][3] : null;
$file5 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][4]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][4] : null;
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors) == true) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name);
            } else {                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name;
                rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
        echo "FILE : $file1<br>";
        echo "FILE : $file2<br>";
        echo "FILE : $file3<br>";
        echo "FILE : $file4<br>";
        echo "FILE : $file5<br>";
    }
}
$orig_directory = "$desired_dir";    //Full image folder
$thumb_directory =  "thumb/";    //Thumbnail folder

/* Opening the thumbnail directory and looping through all the thumbs: */
$dir_handle = @opendir($orig_directory); //Open Full image dirrectory
if ($dir_handle > 1){ //Check to make sure the folder opened

$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_type=array();
$ext='';
$title='';
$i=0;

while ($file_name = @readdir($dir_handle)) {
    /* Skipping the system files: */
    if($file_name=='.' || $file_name == '..') continue;

    $file_type = explode('.',$file_name);    //This gets the file name of the images
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));

    /* Using the file name (withouth the extension) as a image title: */
    $title = implode('.',$file_type);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

    /* If the file extension is allowed: */
    if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types)) {

        /* If you would like to inpute images into a database, do your mysql query here */

        /* The code past here is the code at the start of the tutorial */
        /* Outputting each image: */

        $nw = 100;
        $nh = 100;
        $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
        $stype = explode(".", $source);
        $stype = $stype[count($stype)-1];
        $dest = "thumb/{$file_name}";

        $size = getimagesize($source);
        $w = $size[0];
        $h = $size[1];

        switch($stype) {
            case 'gif':
                $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                break;
            case 'jpg': 
                $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                break;
        }

        $dimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
        $wm = $w/$nw;
        $hm = $h/$nw;
        $h_height = $nh/2;
        $w_height = $nw/2;

        if($w> $h) {
            $adjusted_width = $w / $hm;
            $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
            $int_width = $w / $hm;
            imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,-$int_width,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$w,$h);
        } else {
            imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,0,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
        }
            imagejpeg($dimg,$dest,100);
        }
}

/* Closing the directory */
@closedir($dir_handle);

}
?>
```

When i run code this how am getting out put file, don't know whats going on can some one help me find the error
**Black thumb is created for all type image formate**

When i remove the following code from above code it works what does this code does
[image]

```
if($w> $h) {
        $adjusted_width = $w / $hm;
        $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
        $int_width = $w / $hm;
        imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,-$int_width,0,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
    } else
```

Comment: what file extensions do your files have?

Comment: $source="$desired_dir{$file_name}" ??? Why not $source = $desired_dir."/".$file_name;

Comment: @RaphaelMüller i have JPG,PNG,GIF all image formate

Comment: i've seen in your switch. but you check only against jpg and if the extension is jpeg you'll get a black thumb

Comment: sorry for dump question, but do you send capital letters when send the original file? like JPG,PNG, etc...

Comment: @bksi the source of the file is from same file the previous i upload multiple file from single input

Comment: @RaphaelMüller even in PNG i get black image

Comment: @bksi i have added full processing code

Comment: can you please help me to find error and solve it i don't need any new code

Comment: @sanojlawrence, have you tried `$source = $desired_dir."/".$file_name` instead of `$source="$desired_dir{$file_name}"`? proposed from bksi. And I think all new code suggestions are here, because your code isn't really readable. use at least functions or go for OOP. then you'll be able to reuse code, read the code better and locate errors faster.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller yes i tried `$source = $desired_dir."/".$file_name` still getting same problem

Comment: @sanojlawrence please see my updated answer below.

Comment: You guys could make  voteUP if this question deserve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is located in the following line:

```
imagecopyresampled($dimg, $simg, -$int_width, 0, 0, 0, $adjusted_width, $nh, $w, $h);
```

Why are you using a negative value as destination's x? Your source image is actually put at the left of your target image, so your target image appears empty.

### Solution

I invite you to use the following function to resize your image:

```
function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight)
{
   $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
   $srcHeight = imagesy($img);

   // Determine new width / height preserving aspect ratio
   $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
   $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
   if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight))
   {
      $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
      $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
   }
   else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio)
   {
      $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
      $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
   }
   else
   {
      $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
      $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
   }

   // Creating new image with desired size
   $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);

   // Add transparency if your reduced image does not fit with the new size
   $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
   imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
   imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);

   // Copies image, centered to the new one (if it does not fit to it)
   imagecopyresampled(
      $targetImg, $img, ($targetWidth - $imgTargetWidth) / 2, // centered
      ($targetHeight - $imgTargetHeight) / 2, // centered
      0, 0, $imgTargetWidth, $imgTargetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight
   );

   return $targetImg;
}
```

### Implementation

```
<?php
$newname = md5(rand() * time());
$file1 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][0] : null;
$file2 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][1]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][1] : null;
$file3 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][2]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][2] : null;
$file4 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][3]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][3] : null;
$file5 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][4]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][4] : null;
if (isset($_FILES['files']))
{
   $errors = array ();
   foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
   {
      $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
      $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
      $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
      if ($file_size > 2097152000)
      {
         $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
      }
      $desired_dir = "user_data/";
      if (empty($errors) == true)
      {
         if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false)
         {
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
         }
         if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false)
         {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name);
         }
         else
         {                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name;
            rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
   if (empty($error))
   {
      echo "FILE : $file1<br>";
      echo "FILE : $file2<br>";
      echo "FILE : $file3<br>";
      echo "FILE : $file4<br>";
      echo "FILE : $file5<br>";
   }
   $orig_directory = "$desired_dir";    //Full image folder
   $thumb_directory = "thumb/";    //Thumbnail folder

   /* Opening the thumbnail directory and looping through all the thumbs: */
   $dir_handle = @opendir($orig_directory); //Open Full image dirrectory
   if ($dir_handle > 1)
   { //Check to make sure the folder opened
      $allowed_types = array ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
      $file_type = array ();
      $ext = '';
      $title = '';
      $i = 0;

      while ($file_name = @readdir($dir_handle))
      {
         /* Skipping the system files: */
         if ($file_name == '.' || $file_name == '..')
            continue;

         $file_type = explode('.', $file_name);    //This gets the file name of the images
         $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));

         /* Using the file name (withouth the extension) as a image title: */
         $title = implode('.', $file_type);
         $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

         /* If the file extension is allowed: */
         if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types))
         {

            /* If you would like to inpute images into a database, do your mysql query here */

            /* The code past here is the code at the start of the tutorial */
            /* Outputting each image: */

            $nw = 100;
            $nh = 100;
            $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
            $stype = explode(".", $source);
            $stype = $stype[count($stype) - 1];
            $dest = "thumb/{$file_name}";

            $size = getimagesize($source);
            $w = $size[0];
            $h = $size[1];

            switch ($stype)
            {
               case 'gif':
                  $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                  break;
               case 'jpg':
                  $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                  break;
               case 'png':
                  $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                  break;
            }

            $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
            imagepng($dimg, $dest);
         }
      }

      /* Closing the directory */
      @closedir($dir_handle);
   }
}

function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight)
{
   $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
   $srcHeight = imagesy($img);

   // Determine new width / height preserving aspect ratio
   $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
   $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
   if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight))
   {
      $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
      $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
   }
   else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio)
   {
      $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
      $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
   }
   else
   {
      $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
      $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
   }

   // Creating new image with desired size
   $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);

   // Add transparency if your reduced image does not fit with the new size
   $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
   imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
   imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);

   // Copies image, centered to the new one (if it does not fit to it)
   imagecopyresampled(
      $targetImg, $img, ($targetWidth - $imgTargetWidth) / 2, // centered
      ($targetHeight - $imgTargetHeight) / 2, // centered
      0, 0, $imgTargetWidth, $imgTargetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight
   );

   return $targetImg;
}

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="files[]" type="file"/><br/>
   <input name="files[]" type="file"/><br/>
   <input name="files[]" type="file"/><br/>
   <input name="files[]" type="file"/><br/>
   <input name="files[]" type="file"/><br/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Note: I am saving as PNG, as if you want a 100x100 image using a non-square image (such as 800x600), and without breaking its aspect ratio, we should put transparency behind the unused space and JPEG do not support it.

Comment: am bit confused with above you want me to remove the above resize code or what i should do???

Comment: can please help me whats ERROR in my code so that my code works perfect

Comment: I told you the problem, you are using a negative value for the top/left's horizontal location of the destination image.

Comment: any way thanks form helping me check me question i have removed certain code form question and now it works will that cause any problem

Comment: so what do i do can you please correct this part    `if($w> $h) {
            $adjusted_width = $w / $hm;
            $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
            $int_width = $w / $hm;
            imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,-$int_width,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$w,$h);
        } else`

Comment: replace `-$int_width` by 0

Comment: it works but the image is cropped 60% form left to right the other part is missing

Comment: Your calculations are wrong so this lead to image cropping... you should use aspect ratio, not proportions such as that. Use something like that instead: `$r = ($w / $h);
$nr = ($nw / $nh);
if ($nr > $r) {
   $nw = $nh * $r;
} else if ($nr < $r) {
   $nh = $nw / $r;
}
imagecopyresampled($dimg, $simg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);
` instead. I will not get further here, you have everything to go.

Comment: i get black image in height after certain height anyway thanks i will remove that part and go on

Comment: yeah you meet troubles because your image is sized `100x100` and after resizing you don't get the right size, that's why I suggested you to use transparency. If you do what I told in my answer (to remove the resize part of your code, and add the function I given), you'll get your image in the right format, with transparency and centered. That's your go.

Comment: I just edited my answer so you can now copy/paste the implementation to see it work.

Comment: timblo that's perfect but y do i get transparent image in top and bottom if `W > H` and if `h > w` i get transparent image in sides  i need a 100*100 image it can be stretched i don't need transparent area

Comment: That's because you want a 100x100 image

Comment: it can be stretched 100x100 can be stretched in width and height

Comment: i started typing the error i got but after checking your last comment i got the answer for my question THANKS FOR SOLVING MY QUESTION

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to go for the mime type than the extension.

You'll do this:

```
function check_supported_type($type)
{
    switch($type)
    {
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/gif":
        case "image/png":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

function GetMimeType($file)
{
    //$type = mime_content_type($file); //deprecated

    /* //file info -> normal method, but returns wrong values for ics files..
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    $type = $filename.":".finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    */

    $forbiddenChars = array('?', '*', ':', '|', ';', '<', '>');

    if(strlen(str_replace($forbiddenChars, '', $file)) < strlen($file))
        throw new \ArgumentException("Forbidden characters!");

    $file = escapeshellarg($file);

    ob_start();
    $type = system("file --mime-type -b ".$file);
    ob_clean();

    return $type;
}
```

use it like this:

```
$file = "someimage.jpg";
$mime = GetMimeType($file);
if(check_supported_type($mime))
{
   //do your image processing
}
```

hope this helps

EDIT:

Maybe you can take a look at my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981319/3641016 there you'll see how to generate thumbs.

EDIT:

added the answer to your editet question:

replace:

```
$wm = $w/$nw;
$hm = $h/$nw;
$h_height = $nh/2;
$w_height = $nw/2;

if($w> $h) {
    $adjusted_width = $w / $hm;
    $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
    $int_width = $w / $hm;
    imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,-$int_width,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$w,$h);
} else {
    imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,0,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
}
```

with:

```
if($w > $h)
{
    imagecopyresampled($dimg, $simg, 0,0, ($nw / $h * $w / 2 - $nw / 2),0, $nw,$nw, $h,$h);
}
else
{
    imagecopyresampled($dimg, $simg, 0,0, 0,($nw / $w * $h / 2 - $nw / 2), $nw,$nw, $w,$w);
}
```

and everything should be ok. (if the thumb is quadratic)

Comment: i need to create new image processing or the above code

Comment: no, you don't have to create new image processing code, you can just extend your code with this functions

Comment: if it's not working, you should at least show what errors occured, what did you try etc.

Comment: This is dangerous as you cannot trust the filename (i.e., code injection is possible here if an attacker controls the filename)

Comment: you mean injection to system? I'll have a look how to escape this.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for uploading multiple files and cropping and cropping them.

It uploads the image to a folder, then picks the image, crops it , re-uploads the cropped image and deletes the original image.

Am sure you can play around with this

This is the php code

```
if(isset($_POST['upload_gal']))
{

$fk_id = $_POST['fk_id'];


$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];


   if($file_type=='image/jpeg'||$type=='image/gif'||$type=='image/bmp'||$type=='image/png')
             {
    $image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key]);
    $image_width = $image_info[0];
    $image_height = $image_info[1];

                 $desired_dir="brand_images/";

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0755);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }




            $locationing="brand_images/$file_name";
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$locationing);


             $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("brand_images/$file_name"));
        $rand = rand(111,43943749739349343);
        $filename = "brand_images/$rand-33$file_name";

         if($image_width >= 840 && $image_height >= 680)
        {
        $thumb_width = 1200;
        $thumb_height = 700;
        }else{
        $thumb_width = 800;
        $thumb_height = 533;
        }

        $width = imagesx($image);
        $height = imagesy($image);

        $original_aspect = $width / $height;
        $thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

        if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
        {
           // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
           $new_height = $thumb_height;
           $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
        }
        else
        {
           // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
           $new_width = $thumb_width;
           $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
        }

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

        // Resize and crop
        imagecopyresampled($thumb,
               $image,
               0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
               0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
               0, 0,
               $new_width, $new_height,
               $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 80);

                                                       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO gallery VALUES('','brand_images/$rand-33$file_name','$fk_id')");

        echo"<script>

 window.location = document.URL.replace(/#$/, '');

        </script>";
        }
```

This is the html

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">
       <h3 class="no_margin-top">Upload a new image</h3>
        <hr>
       <input type="hidden" name="fk_id" value="<?php echo $brand->brand_id ?>">
      <input name="upload_gal" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm pull-right btn-success" value="Upload">
     Upload image: <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
     <p class="text-danger top-buffer">If image is larger than 800x533, the image would be cropped</p>
  </form>
```

Comment: can you make some change in your code when i process form there or 5 images in process and how could it work, i need to store orginal file

Comment: Ok. i have changed the bit that deletes the original file.

Comment: When you post 5 images. It would first upload all the original files and then select each one and crops it and it would save the cropped file with this filename "[RANDOM NUMBER]-33[FILE NAME]". Remember to change the folder location from "brand_images" to your folder name

Comment: @Eddy, if sanoj lawrence is the same as in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979402/multiple-image-resize-from-single-input-field/26981319), he isn't realy up to adapt some code. I provided a full working example there.

Comment: Which error? Paste the error here so i can know what to tell you to do

Answer (score 1):

The following code will solve the problem by mapping to the correct imagecreatefrom* function or throw an exception with the invalid image type.

```
switch(strtolower($stype)) {
            case 'gif':
                $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                break;
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                break;
            default:
            throw new \Exception('invalid image type :'.$stype);
            break;
        }
```